# terraform data source remote state doesn't work

Tags: terraform

I have the following terraform :

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "stack" {
  backend = "local"

  config {
    path = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
output "diditwork" {
  value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.stack.aws_autoscaling_group.main.id}"
}
```

and I have a terraform.tfstate file in the same folder :

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "terraform_version": "0.9.3",
    "serial": 14,
    "lineage": "dc16a61f-72dd-435b-ba3f-5e36e14aace2",
    "modules": [
        {
            "path": [
                "root"
            ],
            "outputs": {},
            "resources": {
                "aws_autoscaling_group.main": {
                    "type": "aws_autoscaling_group",
                    "depends_on": [
                        "aws_launch_configuration.lc"
                    ],
                    "primary": {
                        "id": "djin-sample-asg-stag",
                        "attributes": {
                            "arn": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:174120285419:autoScalingGroup:04c470fa-45f8-4711-aa31-b3ede40d6…
```

but for some reason when I do a **terraform apply** my **output doesn't print anything for the autoscaling group id**.  The apply is successful and it doesn't even throw any error. **What am i missing** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
  value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.stack.aws_autoscaling_group.main.id}"
```

You can only get root level outputs in data.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html#root-outputs-only

> Only the root level outputs from the remote state are accessible.
>   Outputs from modules within the state cannot be accessed. If you want
>   a module output to be accessible via a remote state, you must thread
>   the output through to a root output.

So, you will first need to output your autoscaling id, something like:

```
output "asg_id" {
 value = "${aws_autoscaling_group.main.id}"
}
```

And then in the data get, you will do,

```
output "diditwork" {
  value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.stack.asg_id}"
}
```

Also, doing a remote data source on the same location will be a bad idea in general for backends that support locking (or for scenarios where you really want to use it). I am assuming your are doing the remote data source from the same location only for experimental basis, so no harm done, but in real usage, you should just use the value as used in the output above.

Comment: yup experimental only. Figured the root output but just saw that you answered too ! I have an additional problem now which is can use this data source within a module and then use the module to output diditwork ? doesnt seem to work for me. Ill create another question for it.